# What is the most simple way to implement 2 date-pickers in an android fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I can't find a clear cut answer on this.

What is the most simple way to implement 2 date-pickers in an android fragment?

Simply want the dialog when users hit each button and a return value when the user selects one.

Comment: simply use 2 Date Picker dialog. what the issue is ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

Button click:

```
    int select_date = 1;


    et_date1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
            select_date = 1;
            showDatePickerDialog();
         }
    });

    et_date2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            select_date = 2;
            showDatePickerDialog();
        }
    });
```

showDatePickerDialog:

```
    private void showDatePickerDialog() {
    DialogFragment newFragment = new DatePickerFragment();
    newFragment.show(getChildFragmentManager(), "datePicker");
   }
```

DatePickerFragment:

```
    public static class DatePickerFragment extends DialogFragment implements
        DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Use the current date as the default date in the picker
        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

        // Create a new instance of DatePickerDialog and return it
        DatePickerDialog date_picker = new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, year, month, day);

        return date_picker;
    }

    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day) {
        // Do something with the date chosen by the user
        String str_date = day + "/" + (month + 1) + "/" + year;
        if (select_date == 1) {
            et_date1.setText(str_date);
        } else {
            et_date2.setText(str_date);
        }
        select_date = 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should always provide your line of codes to make it easier for everyone to know what you are looking for and how to help you correctly.

However, here is a simple method to call and it will produce a DatePicker:

```
private void showDatePickerDialog(final EditText view) {
    /**
    * @author Mohammed Al-Safwan
    * **/
    final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    int mYear = c.get(Calendar.YEAR); // current year
    int mMonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH); // current month
    int mDay = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH); // current day

    DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(mContext, new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
        /**
         * 
         * @param year selected year. 
         * @param month selected month.
         * @param day selected day.
         * **/
        @Override
        public void onDateSet(DatePicker datePicker, int year, int month, int day) {

        }


    }, mYear, mMonth, mDay);

    // finally, show your dialog
    datePickerDialog.show();
}
```